# Current Date for Query

Tags: date, firebird

I have a query which I currently have to change the date in everytime. I would like to edit it so that it gives me all dates for the current month. Or is there a way to get it to request a date range.

```
SELECT
cast(INTRANSIT.TRANSFERDATE as Date) TheDate,
sum(INTRANSITDETAIL.QTYSHIPPED*INTRANSITDETAIL.SENDINGCOST) Total
FROM
INTRANSIT
INNER JOIN BRANCHES BRANCHESTO ON INTRANSIT.TRANSFERTO = BRANCHESTO.BRANCHNO
INNER JOIN BRANCHES BRANCHESFROM ON INTRANSIT.TRANSFERFROM = BRANCHESFROM.BRANCHNO
INNER JOIN INTRANSITDETAIL ON INTRANSIT.TRANSFERREF = INTRANSITDETAIL.TRANSFERREF
INNER JOIN STOCK ON INTRANSITDETAIL.SKU = STOCK.SKU
INNER JOIN SUPPLIER ON STOCK.INTRECNO_SUPPLIER = SUPPLIER.INTRECNO
LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT ON STOCK.DEPTCODE = DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENTCODE
LEFT JOIN SUBDEPARTMENT ON STOCK.SUBDEPTCODE = SUBDEPARTMENT.SUBDEPTCODE AND SUBDEPARTMENT.DEPTCODE = DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENTCODE
LEFT JOIN SUBSUBDEPARTMENT ON SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.DEPTCODE = DEPARTMENT.DEPARTMENTCODE AND SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.SUBDEPTCODE = SUBDEPARTMENT.SUBDEPTCODE AND SUBSUBDEPARTMENT.SUBSUBDEPTCODE = STOCK.SUBSUBDEPTCODE
WHERE
INTRANSIT.TRANSFERDATE BETWEEN '25 Oct 2014' AND '04 Nov 2014 23:59:59' AND
INTRANSIT.TRANSFERTO <> INTRANSIT.TRANSFERFROM AND
INTRANSIT.TRANSFERTO <> 'B02' AND
INTRANSIT.TRANSFERTO = 'B06' AND
SubString(INTRANSIT.TRANSFERREF FROM 1 FOR 1 ) = 'T' AND
(INTRANSIT.SHIPPER <> 'Central Purchasing' OR
INTRANSIT.SHIPPER IS NULL)
group by 1
```

Comment: You could just get the month and year of the current date with some function and check that the transferdate month and year are equal to the ones of the current date. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please be more specific at what you want to achieve in your question, provide sample data and expected result, and at the same time reduce your query to the minimum needed to illustrate your question. A query with 8 joins seems a bit excessive if you're asking how to query a range of dates.

Comment: Why are you casting `INTRANSIT.TRANSFERDATE` as a `Date`? If a field is a date field, there should be no need to cast anything! You shouldn't store dates as strings!

Comment: I managed to find this "Where                                                                                                                     
  INTRANSIT.TRANSFERDATE BETWEEN dateadd(month, -1, CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) + 1)
    AND CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) " but that gives me for last month and not the current month. I would really like to have just the current months data

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have no future dates in the `INTRANSIT` table, so:

```
where INTRANSIT.TRANSFERDATE between
  dateadd(day,1-extract(day from current_date),current_date) and
  current_timestamp
```

I also suppose you're casting the `TRANSFERDATE` field into a `DATE` type for a purpose, so this field is probably of a `TIMESTAMP` type, hence using of `current_timestamp` and not `current_date`.

.

Comment: I would like to include NULL values as well. Is this possible?